# Trying to understand paging

Tags: paging

So, I am not sure how to make the question detailed. I basically want to understand how paging works. A code that basically performs paging, would be usefull in understanding this. Kinda how to pass pages to frames, virtual memory to physical memory.

I am deeply sorry for my innability to make this clear or detailed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paging Explanation Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004285/paging-explanation-required)

Answer (score 0):

If I m understanding you correctly you probably want something like this to read.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_memory_management.htm